# Monitor Bulk Data Load Jobs Remain "In Progress" even when there are no more batches to complete for the job

Tags: apex, batch

As the title suggests, I am loading data into Salesforce via the Python Simple-Salesforce Library.

For some reason, the jobs that are fully complete, are still showing up as "In Progress".

I click into a job and each batch says "Complete"

Why is this? What can I do about solving this?

Comment: Job needs to be closed by calling [close job](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_quickstart_close_job.htm) api. Is it closed?

Comment: @metasync I would have added this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk API ingestion goes through multiple stages as explained [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_quickstart_requests_intro.htm).

1. Create a Job
2. Add batches
3. Close Job
4. Check for status

Looks like you missed to close the job. If Job is not closed, it stays In Progress for about 24 hours and after that it will error out. Check this [api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_quickstart_close_job.htm) for details on how to close the Job.